How do I check which Windows C++ SDK version(s) I have installed, needed for Rider IDE
When I try to create a new C++ project with Rider I get this window:

Problem is, I don't know what I should write in CppWindowsSdkVersion field. I just updated to latest tools with Visual Studio Installer, and I specifically desire to use latest implemented features.
For reference, in Visual Studio Installer I can see that I have these items available:

C++ 2022 Redistributable MSMs
C++ 2022 Redistributable Update
MSVC v143 - VS 2022 C++ x64/x86 build tools (v14.40-17.10)
C++ Modules for v143 build tools (x64/x86 - experimental)
Windows 10 SDK (10.0.20348.0)

And some others. What number am I looking for / how can I find it? I have checked in MSBuild install directory, in regedit, etc.
Is the version I'm looking for the same as the "Windows 10 SDK"? It's not really clear - there could be a difference btw. Windows 10 SDK version and Cpp SDK version.

If 10.0 was prefilled I would use that.

CppWindowsSdkVersion field corresponds to <WindowsTargetPlatformVersion> in .vcxproj file.
You can find exact version numbers of available SDKs under
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include

While verifying this, I noticed a bug. This field is ignored: RIDER-114176 CppWindowsSdkVersion in project creation dialog is ignored.
To workaroun the issue, open the .vcxproj and set exact SDK version for <WindowsTargetPlatformVersion> tag, for example:
<WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>10.0.22000.0</WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>

